# Pasting macro on linux not working

Tags: c

Program below runs fine on windows. But compilation error occurs on linux 
"error: pasting "." and "config" does not give a valid preprocessing token"

Any reason???  i cant understand why....

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pr {
 int config;
}pr_t;

#define JOIN(x,y) x.##y 

void main()
{

 pr_t temp = {5};

 printf("Value %d\n", JOIN(temp, config)); //temp.config

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: where did you get this idea from of wanting to use a preprocessor paste for that feature?

Answer (score 2):

Try without the ## :)

```
#define JOIN(x,y) x.y
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro concatenation operator, ##, should only be used between two macro parameters.  You have a period between them which serves to delimit the two parameter names.  So as ykatchou suggested, just edit out the ## operator from the macro definition:

```
#define JOIN(x,y) x.y
```

which should still work fine in your windows compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Two tokens that don't together form a ***valid token*** cannot be pasted together using `##`. 
The compiler error says that clearly:

> error: pasting "." and "config" does
>   not give a valid preprocessing token

As suggested by others you can drop `##` altogether.

More info [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2.3/cpp/Concatenation.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with trying to paste a literal string and a token together. This behaviour was changed in gcc 2.7 onwards, see for example the info here:
http://weblog.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/2004/12/30/000/index.html

You should be able to remove the ## and simply concatenate the operators:

```
#define JOIN(x,y) x.y
```